# RSpec Post with a file, params and header field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bdd, rspec-rails

I am trying to test out an api using RSpec for uploading file. The api request is a simple POST request with a file along with some params and also a header field.

I tried making the POST request with the following code:

```
post "media.upload", { client_id: @client.id, token: @client.token, type: @type, name: @name, format: 'json' },
{ 'HTTP_PROXY_SSL' => 'true' }, :upload => @file
```

But I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: post "cm/media.upload", { client_id: @client.id, token: @client.token, type: @type, name: @name, format: 'json' },
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (4 for 1..3)
```

The `@file` variable is defined as:

```
@file = fixture_file_upload(Rails.root + 'spec/fixtures/images/abc.jpg', 'image/jpeg')
```

So my question is how to do a POST request in RSpec with a file, parameters and also some headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `upload` param in with the rest of the request params:

```
params = {upload: @file, client_id: @client.id, token: @client.token, type: @type, name: @name, format: 'json'}
headers = {'HTTP_PROXY_SSL' => 'true'}

post 'media.upload', params, headers
```